# Unable to Bind_ip to mongodb

Tags: database, mongodb, server, nosql, cloud

If I run the command

```
mongo --host 192.168.1.207
```

is shows

> connection attempt failed at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:148  User
>   Assertion: 12513: connect failed exception: connect failed

[Link shows my error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1anjM.png)

Comment: Make sure your `mongod` instance is started with `--bind_ip 192.168.1.207` or `mongo.conf` file

Comment: Oh right, Thanks it helped!